# Word for unintentional omitting of context when telling something

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

It happens when I am deeply focused at something, or I’m completely in my own thoughts, that I tell or ask somebody around me something particular about the subject I am into, but totally forget to give any context regarding this matter. E.g. «Do you know if it has more of an effect at higher altitudes?», where the omitted context could be consuming alcohol.

Is there a word for this, a saying or anything that explains this more specific than my attempt at explaining above.

I want to emphasize that in my question, the omitting of context is unintentional, and an obvious oversight by the questioner on second thought.

Comment: The only word that I can think of is *non-sequitur*, but this is normally used when something doesn't follow logically from what has been said previously.

Comment: Good question. I hope there is a word or phrase that covers this as my wife does it to me all the time! The closest I can think of is "thinking out loud", as that often only consists of the odd phrase or sentence uttered out of context.

Comment: *Apropos of nothing*??  *malapropos*?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I think non-sequitur come closest, as I think _thinking out loud_ describes something that is said with the implication that it may not make sense, and it is not expected that the listener necessarily should reply or completely understand. And I think the thing referred to by _apropos of nothing_ and _malapropos_ may be a meaningful thing to say if you remove the context it was said in (so it no longer become _apropos of nothing_ / _malapropos_), this is almost opposit to what I am asking, where you have do add context to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

**pretermission** :

> 1. neglecting to do something; leaving out or passing over something
> 2. letting pass without notice

**inadvertence** :

> the quality or condition of being inadvertent; heedlessness.

**oversight** :

> an unintentional failure to notice or do something.
> "he said his failure to pay for the tickets was an oversight"

**Absent-minded** :

> of a person or a person's behavior or manner) having or showing a habitually forgetful or inattentive disposition

**Vague** :

> thinking or communicating in an unfocused or imprecise way.
> "he had been very vague about his activities"

**preoccupied** :

> of a matter or subject) dominate or engross the mind of (someone) to the exclusion of other thoughts.
> "his mother was preoccupied with paying the bills